# Finding offset from parent element during drag in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am trying to create a small gui that is similar to a video editor timeline. IE. blocks that can be positioned within the timeline, and expanded or contracted to represent the amount of time that they are active.

I have sort of achieved this by creating a track `<g>` element that acts as a container. The block is represented by another `<g>` element, and inside it there is one `<rect>` and two `<circle>` elements that I am using as handles to allow expansion and contraction of the block. So all together it looks like this:

```
<g class="track-group">
  <g transform="translate(100 0)" class="block-group">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="10"></rect>
    <circle class="left-handle" cx="0" cy="5" r="4"></circle>
    <circle class="right-handle" cx="100" cy="5" r="4"></circle>
  </g>
</g>
```

I have applied the `.drag()` behavior to the two circles. When I drag them however, the `x` value that I get seems to be offset from the inner `<g>` element (`.block-group`). In addition, it seems to sometimes throw up crazy huge values when I try and adjust the block using this offset. I have been trying to find a way so that I can get the x offset from the left side of the `.track-group` `<g>` element. This would make it much easier for me to figure out what to set the x start value of the block.

I tried using `pageX` and `getBoundingClientRect()` of the track element, however this has not seemed to work well either, and the values don't seem to line up. I'm assuming there is a correct way to do this, and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: `x` attribute does not make sense here: `<g x="100" class="block-group">`. You can specify the position of `<g>` by `transform` only

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right. I have modified the example. This was due to the fact that I was trying to replicate the code I had in the example.